# PowerShell: Retrieve a specific internal XML element

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-1.0

I have an XML document with this structure:

```
<Fruits>
    <Fruit>
        <Code>1</Code>
        <Name>Apple</Name>
    </Fruit>
</Fruits>
```

What is the best way to get a `<Fruit>` element by its code (or any other field) in PowerShell 1 code?
(Not XPath, as it is supported in PowerShell 2 only)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use XPath in V1 like this, if you prefer:

```
$xml = [xml](get-content $xmlFile)
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//Fruit[2]")

Code                                                        Name
----                                                        ----
2                                                           Orange
```

Answer (score 5):

You can access the nodes like objects from Posh V1

```
$xml = [xml]"<Fruits>
    <Fruit>
        <Code>1</Code>
        <Name>Apple</Name>
    </Fruit>
    <Fruit>
        <Code>2</Code>
        <Name>Orange</Name>
    </Fruit>
</Fruits>"
$orange = $xml.Fruits.Fruit | ? { [int]$_.Code -eq 2 }
```

Comment: First - thank you.
When trying to run your script: $xml = [xml]" 1 Apple 2 Orange " $orange = $xml.Fruits.Fruit | ? { [int]$_.Code -eq 2 } it throws an exception: "Error: Cannot find an overload for "XmlNode" and the argument count: "3"."
Any idea?

Comment: Hm, weird. Does `$xml.Fruits.Fruit` return anything?

Comment: It's a long time ago I used V1, but I remember that this 'object like' accessing worked. There were some issues, but that won't apply to your example.