# How to get property value from XML file using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm a beginner of powershell,How to get property value  from XML file using PowerShell.
My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<Objs xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04" Version="1.1.0.1">
  -<Obj RefId="0">
    -<Props>
      <S N="Name">Shares</S>
    　<S N="Path">D:\Shares</S>
    </Props>
```

This is what I tried:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content "C:SmbShares.xml")
$xml.Objs.Obj[0].Props.S.N.Name
```

This is the expected result:

```
Shares
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell: Retrieve a specific internal XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911368/powershell-retrieve-a-specific-internal-xml-element)

Comment: Try to remove elements from the right side of the statement `$xml.Objs.Obj[0].Props.S.N.Name` one by one. At which point do you get any output and how does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

I like using Xml Linq library.  You have a default namespace that has to be used.

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$filename = "c:\temp\test.xml"


$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
$ns = $doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()
$s = $doc.Descendants($ns + 'S') 

$name = $s | Where-Object { $_.Attribute('N').Value -eq 'Name' }

Write-Host $name[0].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell's convenient adaption of the XML DOM, i.e. the ability to use *dot notation* to drill into an XML document (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) for background), extends to element and attribute *names*, but not *values*.

Therefore, you must use a *filter* on your `<S>` target elements to find the one whose `N` attribute *value* is `"Name"`:

```bash
$xml.Objs.Obj[0].Props.S.Where({ $_.N -eq 'Name'}).InnerText
```

- The above uses the [intrinsic `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) for filtering.
- Since the `<S>` elements have *attributes*, PowerShell doesn't just return their inner text; it reports them as [`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement) instances. Therefore, the `.InnerText` property must be accessed.